# "Write it down" / "Color the picture" – instructions to pupils

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, word-choice

I teach English to German children. Therefore I would like to know what is the most natural way to tell them to:

> 1. Write (something) down.
> 2. Color the picture

I suspect that it is not enough to say...

> 1. Schreibt es.
> 2. Malt das Bild.

as some "trennbare Verben" would sound more natural in this context, i.e.

> 1. Schreibt es **hin**.
> 2. Malt das Bild **ein**.

Am I right or is there a better (more natural) way to express it?

Comment: "Und dann schreibt ihr/schreibst du es auf". "Und dann malt ihr/malst du es aus". That is not so harsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Schreib es hin!

*Hinschreiben* is a very harsh action. The sentence above means you are already impatient. Consider:

> Setz dich hin!

*Sit down!*

Better use:

> Schreib es (bitte) **auf**!
>
> Schreib es (bitte) **in** dein Heft (hinein/rein)!

---

English

*Color the picture.*

must be translated as

> Färbe das Bild (ein)!

But this is rather formal language, 6-year-olds go better with:

> Mal/Mach (bitte) das Bild bunt!

Comment: Your sentence: "Schreib es (bitte) in dein Heft (hinein/rein)!" implies that the verb "shreiben (in ein Heft)" comes with "Akkusativ". Would it be a big mistake if I were to use "Dativ", as in ""shreiben (in einem Heft)"?

Comment: You are mistaken here. *Schreiben* takes a dative object and/or **a prepositional object** (and/or an object clause). A prepositional object has the case directed by the preposition. I used accusative for **in** because writing something is like *putting your thoughts **into** something*. A direction. Dative is not wrong but implies you are focusing on the exact location instead of the thoughts. *Schreib im Heft, nicht auf dem Tisch!* All three types of object in one sentence: *Schreib ihr in deinem Brief, dass es dir gut geht.*

Answer (score 2):

With respect to part 1 of the question I agree with Janka. I only have to remark that *write down* can also be translated literally as *niederschreiben* but this is rather formal so *hinschreiben* is to be preferred here.

For

> Color the picture.

my preferred translation for this situation is:

> Malt das Bild (farbig) aus.

*Einmalen* does not work. *Einfärben* is OK, but indeed a bit formal.

Comment: The translation in German depends if you're talking to a group "Malt das Bild aus" or a single person (child) "Male das Bild aus".